# Connecting AKG WMS40 Mini Vocal Set to PC

Tags: microphone, pc

I've already bought AKG WMS40 Mini Vocal Set for a gift and just wondering if it can be connected to a basic sound card in laptop. The sound card has 3.5mm jack microphone input and, as the website states, the receiver from AKG WMS4 set provides "one balanced output via 1/4" jack connector". Apart from the 3.5mm/6.3mm jack cable, can this receiver be directly connected to the sound card, or does it need any extra device like mixer etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an mono unbalanced output on the receiver that you can connect to PC/laptop using an mono cable and an adapter however you would yield better quality recordings if using an mixer or external audio interface.

Here's the link to the quick start guide:
http://cloud.akg.com/8361/1377067421783_23_6.pdf